# Animation of adding / removing nodes from VBox

Tags: java, animation, javafx

Method `hide_old_show_new` (I can't think of a suitable name) gradually, using `FadeTransition`, removes all nodes (from last to first) and then adds new nodes (from first to last)

But, it is unnecessarily complex.

Do you know how to simplify it? Or a better algorithm? I'll be grateful for the improvement.

However, I do not want to use an algorithm using *.fxml.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.animation.FadeTransition;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public final class Cart extends javafx.scene.layout.VBox {

    public Cart(double x, double y, double width, double height) {
        super();
        setLayoutX(x);
        setLayoutY(y);
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }

    public FadeTransition hide_old_show_new(ArrayList<Text> nodes) {
        var transition = new FadeTransition();
        var size = getChildren().size();
        if (size > 0 && !getChildren().get(0).equals(nodes.get(0))) {
            transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), getChildren().get(size - 1));
            transition.setFromValue(1);
            transition.setToValue(0);
            transition.setOnFinished((event) -> {
                getChildren().remove(size - 1);
                hide_old_show_new(nodes);
            });
            transition.play();
        } else if (size < nodes.size()) {
            getChildren().add(nodes.get(size));
            getChildren().get(size).setOpacity(0);
            transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), getChildren().get(size));
            transition.setFromValue(0);
            transition.setToValue(1);
            transition.setOnFinished((event) -> {
                hide_old_show_new(nodes);
            });
            transition.play();
        }
        return transition;
    }
}
```

Comment: The question would be better if the entire class was included, right now there really isn't enough to review.

Comment: OK. I've given the whole class. Of course, it is not yet complete.

Answer (score 1):

So I divided it into two methods. This made the conditions considerably easier.

Still, it doesn't seem perfect to me. Plus, I found a mistake. If I run a new animation, an error occurs if the old animation has not been completed yet.

But I don't know how to treat it.

Do you have any idea how, please?

Thank you

```
public FadeTransition hide_old(ArrayList<Text> nodes) {
    var transition = new FadeTransition();
    var size = getChildren().size();
    if (size > 0) {
        transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), getChildren().get(size - 1));
        transition.setFromValue(1);
        transition.setToValue(0);
        transition.setOnFinished((event) -> {
            getChildren().remove(size - 1);
            hide_old(nodes);
        });
        transition.play();
    } else {
        show_new(nodes);
    }
    return transition;
}

private void show_new(ArrayList<Text> nodes) {
    FadeTransition transition;
    var size = getChildren().size();
    if (size < nodes.size()) {
        getChildren().add(nodes.get(size));
        getChildren().get(size).setOpacity(0);
        transition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(200), getChildren().get(size));
        transition.setFromValue(0);
        transition.setToValue(1);
        transition.setOnFinished((event) -> {
            show_new(nodes);
        });
        transition.play();
    }
}
```